# why .call / .bind (from the second time) method ignores the "this" context which is passed to it

Tags: javascript

Please explain why .call / .bind (from the second time) method ignores the "this" context which is passed to it. What is the reason behind it?

```
  var f1= function(){
    console.log(this.name);
};

var a ={name:'sedhu'};
var b= { name:'raja' };

var f2 = f1.bind(a);
f2.call(b);

var f3 = f2.bind(b);
f3();
```

**Actual Output : "sedhu" where expected output is "raja".**

http://jsfiddle.net/sedhuait/uz52ymwn/2/

Comment: you can only bind() `this` once, then it's frozen...

Comment: @dandavis : thanks I got it !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.bind()` function gives you back a function that will always override the value of `this` when invoking the target function. Once you've got a bound function, it will always use that value regardless of how it's invoked.

Thus what you get back from `.bind()` is a function that works (mostly; not exactly) like this:

```
function bindResult() {
  return originalFunction.call(valueForThis, arguments.slice(0));
}
```

That function doesn't care what the value of `this` is in its own invocation context. It *always* uses the value you asked it to. (That's kind-of the whole point of `.bind()`, after all.)

Answer (score 1):

[From the manual](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/function/bind):

> The bind() function creates a new function [...] with the this value bound to the first argument of bind(), which cannot be overridden.